# AngularJS switch expression evaluates but does not trigger correct result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, switch-statement, conditional-statements, ng-switch

I am trying to use a switch to control some image url parameters.  My `image.marketplace` node is a `image.url.indexOf('?')` and evaluates to either `-1` or a positive integer if a question mark is present in the url.  I can get my expression (`ng-switch on="{image.marketplace == -1}"`) to evaluate properly, but it does not trigger the correct "when" condition.  Any thoughts about why?

```
<span ng-switch on="{image.marketplace == -1}">
  <img ng-switch-when="true"  ng-src="{{image.value}}?wid=100&hei=100">
  <img ng-switch-when="false" ng-src="{{image.value}}&wid=100&hei=100">
  <img ng-switch-default      ng-src="{{image.value}}">
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ngSwitchOn](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) directive doesn't require curly brackets, as shown by the documentation. It's probably a better idea to make something like that :

```
<span ng-switch on="isMarketplaced(image)">
  <img ng-switch-when="true"  ng-src="{{image.value}}?wid=100&hei=100">
  <img ng-switch-when="false" ng-src="{{image.value}}&wid=100&hei=100">
  <img ng-switch-default      ng-src="{{image.value}}">
</span>
```

And in the controller :

```
$scope.isMarketplaced = function (image)
{
    return image.marketplace == -1;
}
```

In addition, it will help you to make unit tests on this function.

Comment: Something is still not right...the default case is still getting triggered.

Comment: I've seen that just now, but it's really strange that you have a "true" case, a "false" case *and* a default case. They're not mutually exclusive, what is, I think, not really appreciated by AngularJS. Remove the "false" case and replace it by the default one.

Comment: From the docs on the NgSwitchOn page >> Be aware that the attribute values to match against cannot be expressions. They are interpreted as literal string values to match against. For example, ng-switch-when="someVal" will match against the string "someVal" not against the value of the expression $scope.someVal.